# Can I use ARDL model even if my series aren't stationary?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity, ardl

I have econometric data, and the three tests of unit root: Dickey-Fuller, Phillips–Perron and KPSS have confirmed that more than half of my variables aren't integrated at I(0), nor they are at I(1). I have read in some references that ARDL needs at least all variables to be I(1) (more preferable if they are I(0)), can I use it in my case knowing that my data isn't stationary in both level and at first difference?

Comment: Would you mind using capital letters where appropriate?

Comment: I have made the changes

Comment: Does not look like it. This is how it should be done.

Comment: do you have an answer to my question ?